# After update wamp php 5.6 php insert not working

Tags: php, insert, wamp

After update wamp php 5.6 php insert not working...what i do wrong?
Before update same code work fine.

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
         <input class="insert" name="firstname" required id="firstname-signup" type="text" value="" placeholder="First name"><br><br>
         <input class="insert" name="lastname" required id="lastname-signup" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last neme"><br><br>
         <input class="insert" name="email" required id="email-signup" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
         <input class="insert" name="password" id="password-signup" type="text" value="" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
 <input class="submit" name="submit" id="button-signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
         </form>


<?php    
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

         session_start();
         $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
         $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "INSERT into user ( firstname, lastname, email, password ) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname', '$email', '$password' )";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    header('location: login.php');


     }
?>
```

Comment: Could you expand on _"not working"_, please? Error message on the screen? Checked your error log? Is the mysql-extension installed?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Hash your users passwords as well.

Comment: you're probably outputting before header but not looking for it

Comment: and we don't know if you did connect with the same api here

Comment: `header('location: login.php');` after you have outputted data should give you a `headers already sent`-error

Comment: error reporting and check for errors on the query but am betting on headers sent

Comment: Not working = not insert in database, no errors. Update and select work fine...

Comment: **Check................... for errors** - You say it's working; well then, ok. *bye*

Comment: So, have you checked the error log, or do you mean that you don't see any errors on the screen? Check that error reporting is turned on. Set it to `E_ALL` That code should definitely put stuff in your error log. Please read: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: I move headers but same, not inserting in database..., no errors???

Comment: Did you hit the submit button? Also, where is your $con variable initialised and why are you starting a session that's not being used for anything? Oh.. and why are you letting me delete your users table? https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ifh.png

Comment: $con variable is in same page, session move..., still a same...